# Works in c but gives error in C++

Tags: c++

The below code give no compilation error when used as C file , but gives an error when used as Cpp file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int *delete(int a,int b)
{
    int *p;
    p=&a;
    return p;
}


int main()
{

   return(0);
}
```

Error in C++ file:

- Syntax error
- expected unqualified id before delete
- expected initializer before delete

Comment: `delete` is a keyword.

Answer (score 2):

in c++, "delete" is a keyword(operator) used to free dynamically allocated memory.
It cannot be used to name user defined functions.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, delete is a keyword or an operator which cannot be overridden. 
Thus, C++ compiler will always throw an error as it expects the correct syntax usage.
You can free the memory allocated in heap using "delete".